# How to get Futures of actor invocation in a non-actor context

Tags: java, akka, future

I'm integrating Akka in an existing software, mainly to make things asynchronous where they shouldn't be synchronous.

I've a service that is making some database calls, at the moment, everything is synchronous, the calling thread is just sitting here and waiting for the result...

My idea is to replace the DAO interface to have `Future<T>` (Akka's) as results instead of actual result types, thus, my DAO implementation is actually transforming those call in messages and routes them to appropriate actors (local and/or remote).

Now I'm a bit puzzled when it comes to how to return a `Future<T>` when I call the actor. Is there any other way than using `Patterns.ask()` ? Is it the best solution performance-wise (without rewriting everything using actors) ?

Using `Patterns.ask()`, how could I return an error without waiting for the timeout ? If the actor I call simply tells back the error, it would trigger a success, when I want to trigger a failure.

**Edits**

I'm using Java.

Right now, I came up with a construct like the one below, but, it implies my actor has to `tell()` the exception back to the sender.

```
final Future<Object> f = Patterns.ask(..., ..., ...);
f.flatMap(new Mapper<Object, Future<List<Element>>>() {
    public Future<List<Element>> apply(Object response) {
        if (response instanceof SuccessfulResult) { 
            return Futures.successful(response, f.executor());
        } else if (response instanceof Throwable) {
            return Futures.failed((Throwable) response, f.executor());
        } else {
            return Futures.failed(..., f.executor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate between success or failure you would use [scala.Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Either.html). So the answer type could look something like this:

```
type Result = Future[Either[SQLException, MyDataType]]
```

Comment: I'm using Java, but I guess it doesn't really matter... In your case, the `Future<T>` will call `onFailure()` if I return an `SQLException`, should I simply throw the `Exception` in my actor ?

Comment: The docs is a good place to start: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/java/untyped-actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Viktor, didn't notice the `Failure` before. What happens if this is done in an actor context ? The caller would receive the `Failure` as a normal message, right ?